# How do I switch first/last name order in the iOS address book?

Tags: ios, contacts

My contacts are arranged by last name first in my iPad and iPhone and I want to have them first name then last name. Where do I access the address book preferences?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to **Settings**.
2. Scroll down and click the **Mail, Contacts, and Calenders** preference.
3. Now, scroll until you are under *Contacts* heading.
4. Select the **Sort Order** option.
5. Choose which way you want to sort your contacts.